# Combining generic function argument types

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I want typescript to accept a list of arguments that have similar structures but with disparate values and infer correctly the resulting union type.

Sample code

```
interface User<
    N extends string = string,
    S extends unknown = unknown,
    A extends (a: S) => unknown = (a: S) => unknown
> {
    name: N;
    state: S;
    action: A;
}

function createUser<
    N extends string = string,
    S extends unknown = unknown,
    A extends (a: S) => unknown = (a: S) => unknown
>(name: N, state: S, action: A): User<N, S, A> {
    return { action, name, state };
}

function combineUsers<
    V extends User<string, unknown, (a: unknown) => unknown>[]
>(...users: V) {
    type Names = V[number]["name"];
    return {
        actions: users.reduce(
            (a, u) => ({ ...a, [u.name]: u.action }),
            {} as { [K in Names]: Extract<V[number], { name: K }>["action"] },
        ),
        names: new Set<Names>(users.map((u) => u.name)),
    };
}

const userA = createUser("user1", 1, (_a: number) => undefined);
const user2 = createUser("userB", "two", (_s: string) => true);
const users = combineUsers(userA, user2);
// Argument of type 'User<"user1", number, (_a: number) => undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User<string, unknown, (a: unknown) => unknown>'.
//   Type '(_a: number) => undefined' is not assignable to type '(a: unknown) => unknown'.
//     Types of parameters '_a' and 'a' are incompatible.
//       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

That is the compilation error I get because of the incompatible functions.

What I would expect to see as type returned by the function is some inferred union like;

```
type Return = {
    names: Set<"user1" | "userB">,
    actions: {
        user1: (_a: number) => undefined;
        userB: (_s: string) => boolean;
    }
}
```

- Is this even possible? Can sprinkle `any` but I'd rather not
- Are there any alternatives or better ways of achieving this

EDIT:

The solution by @jcalz worked great for the problem as stated in the previous version but my sample was missing something to make it applicable to my actual code, i.e. when the argument of a function must match a type defined elsewhere.

Comment: I have an answer for this, but... in `createUser()`, is`fnArgs` just a dummy parameter to give the compiler a hint about the type of arguments the `action` method will take?  It sure looks like it, but what's the point, when the methods in question will just return the `returnValue` value no matter what?  Why the complexity of `(...args: A)=>R` when you might as well just use `() => R`?  Or, why doesn't `createUser` actually take a *function* of type `(...args: A)=>R` and not *values* of type `A` and `R`?  It's a weird/distracting example. Can you modify it?

Comment: Sure, can modify it. Was just trying to create a stripped down version of my actual code. Lot of the stuff in this example is superfluous to give the question context.

Answer (score 1):

The typing I'd give to `combinedUsers` looks like this:

```
function combineUsers<V extends User<string, never[], unknown>[]>(...users: V) {
  type Names = V[number]['name'];
  return {
    actions: users.reduce(
      (a, u) => ({ ...a, [u.name]: u.action }),
      {} as { [K in Names]: Extract<V[number], { name: K }>['action'] }
    ),
    names: new Set<Names>(users.map((u) => u.name)),
  };
}
```

Note that there's just one generic type parameter, `V`, corresponding to the array of `User<N, A, R>` objects passed in.  The type parameters `string` (covariant upper bound constraint for property types), `never[]` (contravariant lower bound constraint for argument types), and `unknown` (covariant upper bound constraint for return value types) are slightly more type safe than `any`, `any`, `any`, but could still allow some weird inputs.  Hopefully that doesn't actually matter though.

Inside the implementation we define `Names` type to grab the union of `N` parameters for each element of `V` (`V[number]['name']` is the type you get when you index into `users` with a `number` index and then index into the resulting `User` with a `"name"` index).

The type of the `actions` property a mapped type where for each name in `Names` we find the element(s) of `V` that have that as their `name` and get its `action` type.

---

Let's see if it works.  Assuming you have a `userA` and `user2` of these types:

```
//const userA: User<"user1", [x: number, y: string], undefined>
//const user2: User<"userB", [x: string], boolean>
```

Then you `combineUsers(userA, user2)` results in this:

```
const users = combineUsers(userA, user2);
/* const users: {
    actions: {
        user1: (x: number, y: string) => undefined;
        userB: (x: string) => boolean;
    };
    names: Set<"user1" | "userB">;
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoB4BQzkByyEAHpCACbrLphSgDmyAvDXYwDR7ICCxZEStQCuIANYgA9gHcQAbQC6LZKIkz5CrvgBKy1VNncAfMgDe3EHAC2EAFyEA3N0RhgkkPYAUAOl9woDOj2PACULCbaTgC+ODgwogiu7sgIUBBwkBjY3ESk5FRs9CBMrLRFDFq8-Pki4gYaenXqipW6rPrqOEaeljb2BBzILm4eyD5+wWHMESH2WVBYA7yD2ibm+GlgwlAgZkOJI4O9KFHRsfEgB8kIklYARqAQ8+i4+ABq1YIF81hlnMggCAAN2gLRUTVkRhaxnG3mEmCgQWQbzC62QYAAngAHFAEawQaisN5yEDCe7QBRyADkxypCicGwgWx2Zm4+GG7iR8Og6G8aQowiQnjZ+DGcEGwimJk8pmQvm84uQcmE3mOCnsKo5uyiIUqorMUSG1FlcgA0shQIR8eh1cgAKJkKAuLDE0nkqCaPbHezmqJQqlaunIGL63Ui45IwHSZAAZSZi2t3W5iO8VjgWM8nkl4RUqvxITD+FOyBwMRwNxAtBUCL4rFS6UyCOF+AARMmAIwtwaeEj2N13aCDDH2P7FKXcTwV9CSAA2EG8M8kDB7yAA1Mh20PvGBJKgsTioABhOCYTwFiWUCAwR4UAtOAD095SnLA1egPDmCKwbYRncGcl7AEyQHKAhxHdhik9UQKCvG8jHLF83ygAAmZR6wyJ4mx-aAACEuwnQDRwYKVkBIBdBAYMAAAtkCwZAABYQgfe8p1fZNkM-bBsKgPD-0IiCGE9O5JFndIQHghDKzYhFCWfe5HmeLMawlBFkKYnB7wAKmfKSkKRNF2SuSt7AM-UkPbLxAP7QdkGHQpGBI6DYMBCgGTM-BkxwyzwPKEjhNEuAQDcotgoBa17DjMBvw7FtkAAH2Qbi8KMaJkE0+8cGTXktV5DtPE3RL3AgFsmOQR9kGQwYWwAeQIO0W0k6c5wXJclJ5BUjNyhEcM8FsB2Ku8yqfOhhAgHAgA)

Comment: Thanks! But sadly I missed something in the original problem statement which I have added to the question now. But this did point me in hopefully the right direction. If you want to review the update that would be great too!